# Pass clicks through Tkinter window? Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, wxpython, autopy

Is there a way to make a Tkinter window unclickable? Meaning that any input that should be caught by the handler are redirected to whatever window is behind it? If not in Tkinter, would there be a way in PyQt or wxPython? My goal is to have a handler catch keyboard events while still letting them input into the windows behind. I don't need to catch clicks but that would be nice to have if possible.

**My current plan:**

A Tkinter window with a geometry of 10000x10000, alpha of 0 and topmost set to true. The frame will catch all keyboard & mouse events and when anything is entered the frame will catch it, hide the Tkinter window using an apple script function which is run from terminal with osascript, use autopy to simulate whatever was entered such as a click/keyboard event and unhide the window again. Does this even sound viable?

When I have the time I will test out this idea and post if it works. I'm thinking computation speed will be an issue here.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? You can grab every click without resorting to covering the screen with a transparent window. What do you need to steal clicks that are over other windows?

Comment: As stated above: capture keyboard input while still letting them input into other windows. The clicks are the least of my concern. I mainly want a way to catch the keyboard input. I realize covering the screen is a horrible and dirty way to do it but if you have any other suggestions I'd be more than happy to hear.